# Python - Scrapy SgmlLinkExtractor Deny Value Is Being Ignored

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using Scrapy to crawl http://www.investopedia.com.

I have a crawl filter definition in my "Spider.py" file:

```
rules = (
    # Crawl filters
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(deny=settings['DENY_FILTER']), callback='parse_item', follow=True, process_links='process_links'),
)
```

**settings['DENY_FILTER']** is being pulled from the "settings.py" file and no matter how I format it, the crawler will not filter (or "deny") what I'm asking it to. The deny values are as follows:

```
DENY_FILTER     =   (re.compile('((?!(\?|&)page=(\d)+)\?.*)', re.I), re.compile('/markets/stocks/', re.I), re.compile('/errorpage/', re.I))
```

I have also tried using an uncompiled version of the Regex to no avail:

```
DENY_FILTER     =   ('((?!(\?|&)(p|P)age=(\d)+)\?.*)', '/markets/stocks/', '/(e|E)rror(p|P)age/')
```

I've searched the internet for days and have come up with no answers so now I turn to you StackOverflow. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass `deny` arguments in place

```
Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(deny=('regexp1', 'regexp2',),...
```

If your deny rules will work, I think you should access `DENY_FILTER` defined in `settings.py` as:

```
DENY_FILTER =  ('regexp1', 'regexp2',)
```

by writing:

```
Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(deny=settings.DENY_FILTER), ...
```

Also, please show `process_links` function code?